# How to apply sort and uniq having the same input and output file in Unix?

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, io-redirection

I want to apply some operation(intersection and reunion) on two or more text files
so after I put all rows together I have to apply sort and uniq on that file.
The problem is that I want to have the same input and output file (-i doesn't work).
Here is my code:

```
  nr_param=$#
    case $1 in

    '-r')
        if [ "$nr_param" = 3 ]
        then
            echo "reuniunea"
            rm -f reuniune1.txt
            cat $2 $3 >> reuniune1.txt
            sort <reuniune1.txt | uniq >reuniune.txt 
            rm -f reuniune1.txt
        else
            echo "parametri incorecti"
        fi;;
    '-i') 
        if [ "$nr_param" = 3 ]
        then
            echo "intersectia"
            rm -f intersectie.txt
            grep -Fx -f $2 $3 > intersectie.txt
        else
            echo "parametri incorecti"
        fi;;
```

Could you help me do the same thing without using an extra file?
The same for grep if $2 would be "intersectie.txt".

Comment: See updated answer, it may help you. If an answer helps you, feel free to upvote or accept the answer using the green check mark near the top left of the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit --

I wrote below when I was half asleep, ;-) and there's a great shortcut for your case

```
  sort -u -o file file
```

The `-u` option makes the sorted data uniq, and as mentioned below, `-o file` will save the output to any file your care to name, including the same name as the input.

If you want to do something like

```
  sort < file | uniq -c > uniqFileWithCounts
```

Then the first idea won't help you.

---

Don't kid yourself, even when you use `sort -o file file` to reuse the same filename for the sorted `-o`(utput), behind the scenes the system has to write all of the data to a tmp file and then rename to the file specified by `-o file` (Also sort is writing intermediate sort data to the `/tmp` dir and deletes that when the final output is complete).

So you're best bet is something like

```
sort <reuniune1.txt | uniq > uniqd.txt && mv uniqd.txt reuniune1.txt
```

This will only overwrite  reuniune1.txt if the `sort | uniq` process exits without error.

IHTH